# Financing of an equity forward

Tags: equities, forward

How reasonable it is to assume that the forwards (implied through call-put parity from European options) on easy-to-borrow European stocks will "grow" at Euribor/Eonia rate? In other words, is it reasonable to assume that we can finance the stock hedge at Euribor/Eonia (given we leave the stock as collateral).

Comment: In principle the stock is financed at its repo rate. This is why the forward obtained from call/put parity is a measure of "implied" repo & dividends.

Comment: to add to that, stock repo pricing can vary wildly from stock to stock, and there is of the required consideration of reasonable haircuts to mitigate volatility